# How to test vista compatiblity for web applications?

Tags: testing

I don't have microsoft vista installed. Is there some kind of trial edition windows vista install in a vmware that can let us test for web application compatilibty?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use Virtual PC:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en

And download the application compatibility testing images MSFT provides at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

+1 VirtualPC, though the whole expiry thing is incredibly annoying!

However, FWIW there is almost zero difference between IE7-on-Vista and IE7-on-XP, webapp-compatibility-wise. The differences are platform-level security things that won't generally affect you.